# Docker Postgres storage persistance and initializing the database on local

Tags: database, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

So! Recently began transitioning over to Docker and I'm hitting a snag.  I have a local Postgres database that I'm trying get into the container and then persist after the container is running.  However, my postgres container within Docker is not creating my database properly (or at all) when I `docker-compose up` or `docker-compose up --build` it. I'm mostly getting a `FATAL: database "yourappdb" does not exist` error.

**Background on the app:**
For the sake of this post, it's a Flask/Python API with Postgres.  It uses SQLAlchemy to handle the connection.

**The Docker Setup**
I use a SQL file generated from my local database to try and populate the DB inside of the Docker Postgres container.  As I understand it, I use the initdb entry point to facilitate this.

**The errors I'm seeing**
Unfortunately, I've seen a couple of different errors as I mentioned in the intro.  I'm wondering if there's some sort of caching going on when building the container that's not seeing the changes?

- `FATAL: database "yourappdb" does not exist` - This is the primary error.  It appears the database isn't being created at all.
- The second error is strange.  While running `docker-compose up --build` after making a change to the yourappdb.sql file...I saw it run a few tries ago!  It said the user/owner "myname" didn't exist yet.  I've not been able to reproduce this.

**What I've tried**

- I tried creating the user/password for the db before the tables inside of the .sql file (as seen below).
- I tried using an init-user script mentioned in the postgres docker hub docs to create the user before the database (you can see the mention of it commented out in the docker-compose file).
- I tried creating a volume between the sql file and the /data library in the docker container?

**Final notes**
So after all of these attempts and removing the image/container so many times and rebuilding over and over...I connected to postgres bash and then psql -U postgres.  I found a database there called `myname` instead of `yourappdb` and inside it was ONLY the first table out of the 15 or so tables I wanted to make.  What the heck?  So it seems like it at some point tried to make a db, but didn't use the right database name and gave up part of the way.

Any help is much appreciated.  I'm trying to persist the data as well, but I can't even get through the initial data creation.

Postgres/Dockerfile

```
# base image
FROM postgres:10.4-alpine

# run the db file on init
ADD yourappdb.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

Docker-Compose.yml

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  postgres:
    build:
      context: ./postgres
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 5435:5432
    volumes:
      - './postgres/pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
      # - './postgres/yourappdb.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/yourappdb.sql'
      # - './postgres/init-user-db.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-user-db.sh'
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=myname
      - POSTGRESS_PASSWORD=test
      - POSTGRES_DATABASE=yourappdb
  api:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./server
    volumes:
      - './server:/usr/src/app'
    ports:
      - 5001:5000
    environment:
      - FLASK_APP=server/index.py
      - FLASK_ENV=development
      - APP_SETTINGS=config.DevelopmentConfig
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://myname:test@postgres:5432/yourappdb
      - DATABASE_TEST_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@postgres:5432/yourappdb
    depends_on:
      - postgres
```

A portion of the SQL file.

```
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

-- Dumped from database version 9.6.5
-- Dumped by pg_dump version 9.6.5

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET row_security = off;

--
-- Name: plpgsql; Type: EXTENSION; Schema: -; Owner: 
--

CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS plpgsql WITH SCHEMA pg_catalog;


--
-- Name: EXTENSION plpgsql; Type: COMMENT; Schema: -; Owner: 
--

COMMENT ON EXTENSION plpgsql IS 'PL/pgSQL procedural language';


SET search_path = public, pg_catalog;

SET default_tablespace = '';

SET default_with_oids = false;

--
-- Name: administrator; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: myname
--

CREATE TABLE administrator (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    "timestamp" timestamp without time zone,
    email character varying(255)
);


ALTER TABLE administrator OWNER TO myname;
```

I've also tried including this in the .sql file

```
CREATE USER myname WITH PASSWORD 'test';
CREATE DATABASE yourappdb;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE yourappdb TO myname;
/c yourappdb;
```

By the way, this app runs fine locally and connects to the db, etc.